# Is Hebrews 4:13 a quote from the book of Enoch?

Tags: hebrews, 1-enoch, apocrypha

Young's Literal Translation

***and there is not a created thing not manifest before Him, but all things are naked and open to His eyes -- with whom is our reckoning***.

Book of Enoch

Chapter 1X

5. Thou hast made all things, and power over all things hast Thou: and ***all things are naked and open in Thy sight, and Thou seest all things, and nothing can hide itself from Thee***

Is the author of the book of Hebrews quoting the book of Enoch? .

Answer (score 1):

The short answer appears to be, "YES" - Heb 4:13 seems to quote 1 Enoch 9:5 as correctly observed by the OP.

The author Hebrews does not say this explicitly, but such a lack of attribution is the norm in the NT, even when it quotes the OT.

The "Comprehensive New Testament" (Cornerstone Publications) provides an extremely extensive list of such allusions and quotes from non-Biblical sources from throughout the NT - a useful reference.

FOOTNOTE - There are actually three ancient works called "Enoch":

1. 1 Enoch in the Ge'ez language from about 150 BC(?)
2. 2 Enoch in Old Slavonic from about 100 AD(??)
3. 3 Enoch in Hebrew from about 400 AD(??)

The above quote is from the first book of Enoch.

Comment: Interesting!  Didn’t know this. Does the learning ever stop.